# pg_upgrade tool failed: invalid "unknown" user columns

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql update from 9.6 to 10.4 (on Fedora 28) has me stuck: one table in one database has a column of data type "unknown". I would gladly remove the column, but since I cannot get postgresql service to start (because "An old version of the database format was found"), I have no access to the database. In more detail:

`postgresql-setup --upgrade` fails.

`/var/lib/pgsql/upgrade_postgresql.log` attributes this failure to column with data type "unknown": "...Checking for invalid 'unknown' user columns: fatal .... check tables_using_unknown.txt". And "tables_using_unknown.txt" specifies one column in one table that I wish I could drop, but can't, because I can't get the server to start:

`systemctl start postgresql.service` fails, and 
systemctl status postgresql.service complains about the "old version of the database"

I have found no obvious way to install postgresql 9.6 on Fedora 28.

Is there a way to drop the column without a running server? Or at least produce a dump of the database? Or can I force the upgrade tool to drop columns with data type "unknown"? Or is there any other obvious solution that I'm missing?

Comment: Hi Heiko. I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @filippo, I'm so glad I'm not alone with my issue :-). I posted what worked for me (as an answer to my own question) -- not sure how general a solution this is, but I'm keeping my fingers crossed that it solves your issue, too!

Comment: Nice solution. I'll try it and let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what finally worked for me:

- I used a docker container (on the same machine) with postgres 9.6 to access the "old" database directory,
- converted the problematic column from "unknown" to "text" in the container,
- dumped the relevant database to a file on the container's host, and then
- loaded the dumped db into the postgres 10.4 environment.

Not pretty, but worked. In more detail:

I copied postgresql's data directory (`/var/lib/pgsql/data/` in Fedora) -- containing the database that could not be converted -- to a new, empty directory `/home/hj/pg-problem/`.

I created a Dockerfile (text file) called "Docker-pg-problem" reading

```
FROM postgres:9.6
# my databases need German locale; 
# if you just need en_US, comment the next two lines out.
RUN localedef -i de_DE -c -f UTF-8 -A /usr/share/locale/locale.alias de_DE.UTF-8
ENV LANG de_DE.utf8
```

and saved it as the only file in the new, empty folder `/home/hj/pg-problem/docker/`.

I started the docker daemon and ran a container *that uses the data from my copy of the problematic data* (in `/home/hj/pg-problem/data/`) as data directory for the postgres 9.6 server in the container. (NB: the "docker build" command in line three needs a working internet connection, takes a while, and should finish saying "Successfully built").

```
root@host: cd /home/hj/pg-problem/docker
root@host: service docker start
root@host: docker build -t hj/failed-update -f Dockerfile .
root@host: docker run -it --rm -p 5431:5432 -v /home/hj/pg-problem/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z --name failed-update -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret hj/failed-update
```

Then, I opened a terminal in the container to fix the database:

```
hj@host: docker exec -it failed-update bash
```

Inside the container, I fixed and dumped the database:

```
root@container: su postgres
postgres@container: psql <DB-name>
postgres@container: alter table <Table-name> alter column <Col-Name> type text;
postgres@container: \q
postgres@container: dump_db <DB-name> /var/lib/postgresql/data/dbREPAIRED.sql
```

I dumped the db right into the data directory so I could easily access the dumped file from the docker host.

On the docker host, the dumped database was, obviously, in `/home/hj/pg-problem/data/dbREPAIRED.sql`, and from there I could load it into postgresql 10:

```
postgres@host: createdb <DB-name>
postgres@host: psql <DB-name> < /home/hj/pg-problem/data/dbREPAIRED.sql
```

Since I was on a laptop with limited disk space, I deleted the docker stuff:

```
root@host: docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
root@host: docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```